# Android architecture components paging DataSource.Factory error

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-paging

I'm trying to make my `DataSource.Factory` class, but I get an error when trying to return my `PageKeyedDataSource` implementation.

```
class SubredditPageKeyedDataSource(private val service: LedditService,
                               private val subredditName: String): PageKeyedDataSource<String, Children<DataX>>() {

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<String>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<String, Children<DataX>>) {
    service.getSubredditTopics(subredditName).subscribe { result -> callback.onResult(result.data.children, result.data.before, result.data.after) }
}

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<String>, callback: LoadCallback<String, Children<DataX>>) {
    service.getSubredditTopicsAfter(subredditName, after = params.key).subscribe {result -> callback.onResult(result.data.children, result.data.after)}
}

override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<String>, callback: LoadCallback<String, Children<DataX>>) {
    // ignored, since we only ever append to our initial load
}
```

}

Now heres my factory:

```
class SubredditDataSourceFactory(private val service: LedditService,
                             private val subredditName: String): DataSource.Factory<String, List<Children<DataX>>>() {


override fun create(): DataSource<String, List<Children<DataX>>> {
    return SubredditPageKeyedDataSource(service, subredditName)
    }
}
```

When returning my DataSource in the above `create()` method, AndroidStudio gives me an IDE error:

```
Type mismatch. 
Required: DataSource<String, List<Children<DataX>>>
Found: SubredditPageKeyedDataSource
```

Am I going insane? `PageKeyedDataSource` extends from `ContiguousDataSource` which is a `DataSource`. Why am I getting a type mismatch? I've checked 2 different examples of the paging library and their implementation is exactly like mine. Unless I missed something???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types don't actually match.

Your factory is for:

```
PageKeyedDataSource<String, List<Children<DataX>>>
```

But your datasource implements the type:

```
PageKeyedDataSource<String, Children<DataX>>
```

Notice that one has a list of children on the right side, the other a single child.
The one without the List<> should be correct, try removing that part from your code.

Comment: Thanks, knew It was probably some sort of oversight on my part.